# Racket List Error Using Recursion

Tags: racket

I am trying to complete a school problem using lists in Racket. It is a simple problem using recursion but I cannot understand why my code won't work. We are supposed to search the list and return true if the item provided matches one in the list. This is what I have so far:

```
(define (containsAnywhere test  list)
  (cond 
    ((null? list) '())
    (equal?((car list) test))
    (else(containsAnywhere (test (cdr list))))))
```

But I get the following error:

```
application: not a procedure;
 expected a procedure that can be applied to arguments
  given: 1
  arguments.:
```

Answer (score 2):

A few comments:

- don't call your parameter `list`, there's a build-in procedure of that name which will be shadowed this way; in Scheme it's common to call the parameter `lst` instead
- you have a lot of parentheses errors - procedure calls are like `(procedure param1 param2 ...)`, the conditions inside `cond` are in parentheses
- the `equal?` predicate has a trailing `?`
- and your code's indentation is off; use Dr Racket's "reindent all" feature
- I assume the result of your procedure is supposed to be True or False, so the empty list should return `#f`, not `'()`

Here's a working version of your code; inside `cond` I put the condition and the expression to be evaluated on separate lines so that the code and the parentheses become clearer:

```scm
(define (containsAnywhere test lst)
  (cond 
    ((null? lst)
     #f)
    ((equal? (car lst) test)
     #t)
    (else
     (containsAnywhere test (cdr lst)))))
```

Alternatively, I would code this like:

```scm
(define (containsAnywhere tst lst)
  (and (not (null? lst))
       (or (equal? (car lst) tst)
           (containsAnywhere tst (cdr lst)))))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
(test (cdr list))
```

Here you're applying `test` to the argument `(cdr list)` as if `test` were a function, but it's not. Thus the error.

You presumably meant `(containsAnywhere test (cdr list))`, which passes `test` as the first argument to `containsAnywhere` and `(cdr list)` as the second.